# Encoding arbitrary data for stream transmission

Tags: c, stream, tcp, escaping

Basically, what this function should do is encode an arbitrary set of data in memory to a series of bytes that starts with `0x02`, ends with `0x03`, and encodes each instance of `0x02`, `0x03`, or `0x25` by preceding it with `0x25`. It does this to make it safe for stream transmission, for example, a TCP socket. It returns a non-null-terminated array of `char` allocated with `malloc` (and therefore must be `free`d by the caller) and the length of the new array.

```
size_t encodedata(char** outdata, const void* data, size_t size)
{
    const char* dchr = data;
    size_t n = 2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        n += dchr[i] == 0x02 ? 2 : dchr[i] == 0x03 ? 2 : dchr[i] == 0x25 ? 2 : 1;

    char* encdata = malloc(n);

    encdata[0] = 0x02;
    encdata[n-1] = 0x03;

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 1; i < size && j < (n - 1); i++) {
        if (dchr[i] == 0x02 || dchr[i] == 0x03 || dchr[i] == 0x25)
            encdata[j++] = 0x25;
        encdata[j++] = dchr[i];
    }

    *outdata = encdata;
    return n;
}
```

The `main` function, which tests `encodedata`, runs without problems:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* out;
    char* in = "1" "\x02" "%" "\x03" "3";

    size_t n = encodedata(&out, in, 6);

    printf("size: %d\n", n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%x ", out[i]);

    printf("\n");

    assert(n == 11);
    assert(out[0] == 0x02);
    assert(out[1] == '1');
    assert(out[2] == 0x25);
    assert(out[3] == 0x02);
    assert(out[4] == 0x25);
    assert(out[5] == 0x25);
    assert(out[6] == 0x25);
    assert(out[7] == 0x03);
    assert(out[8] == '3');
    assert(out[9] == 0x00);
    assert(out[10] == 0x03);

    free(out);
}
```

Comment: Hi, is your byte stuffing method a mandatory specification? In worst case, the data stream is doubled in length plus 2 bytes for start and end flag. Have a look to Consistent Overhead Byte Stuffing (COBS). It is also easier to handle the additional size of data.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the encoding format itself is not subject to review, it's a pretty good implementation. Things that could be improved (small stuff):

- Chaining `?:` is not necessary here, compare:

  ```
  n += dchr[i] == 0x02 ? 2 : dchr[i] == 0x03 ? 2 : dchr[i] == 0x25 ? 2 : 1;
  ```

  to:

  ```
  n += (dchr[i] == 0x02 || dchr[i] == 0x03 || dchr[i] == 0x25) ? 2 : 1;
  ```
- Prefer `unsigned char*` for work on raw binary sequences, `char*` means a string of text by convention
- `0x02`, `0x03`, and `0x25` all have meanings, so better give them meaningful names, e.g.

  ```
  const unsigned char ENC_START = 0x02, ENC_END = 0x03, ENC_ESCAPE = 0x25;
  ```
- In the test:

  ```
  char* in = "1" "\x02" "%" "\x03" "3";
  size_t n = encodedata(&out, in, 6);
  ```

  it's not clear where `6` came from, so I'd opt for:

  ```
  char in[] = "1" "\x02" "%" "\x03" "3";
  size_t n = encodedata(&out, in, sizeof(in));
  ```

Moreover, unless the function signature you proposed is a requirement, I would opt for a buffered design that encodes data in chunks on the fly. It's a little more complicated because you would need to remember the state between calls -- how much input data was processed so far (think of `fread`). For stream transmission, you probably call `encodedata`, send the result, and throw it away immediately after. So elliding `malloc` and relieving the caller from encoding the whole stream at once are both welcome here. One of many possible designs may look like this:

```
struct encodestate
{
    void* in;
    size_t inlen;
    unsigned char out[256];  // use apprioprate chunk length for your stream
    size_t outlen;
};

/* Writes encoded data into state.out, updates state.outlen
   and for internal use updates state.in and state.inlen.

   Returns whether there's more input data to process (should be called again).
*/
bool encode(struct encodestate* state);
```

Example of use:

```
unsigned char in[] = "1" "\x02" "%" "\x03" "3";

for (struct encodestate state = {in, sizeof in}; encode(&state); )
    send(somewhere, state.out, state.outlen);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't check whether `malloc()` failed.
2. As you are sure you have enough memory, consider trading some memory for making the algorithm one-pass: The encoded result is at most \$2*size+2\$ long.
   If you aren't quite so sure, consider only pre-calculating the real size if over-allocation fails.
3. Simplify your conditional-operator-chain.
4. Consider changing the calculation of `n` so you only add the space for the escape-character in the loop. That might be more efficient.
5. Actually, consider *not* allocating any memory in your function, as it's likely to be called quite often and allocation is both costly and often unneccessary. Instead of passing an out-parameter, pass a buffer and length.
6. `char` can have a trap representation or a negative zero. Consider working with `unsigned char` instead, like the standard library does (even if the interface says plain `char`).
7. Consider using `memcmp()` for writing your test-case.